# Spring Boot Caching with Redis - Deserialisation issue

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, redis, deserialization

I have tried to implement caching mechanism using Redis in my Spring Boot project. I'm using MySQL as my database and want to cache some data in in-memory database (Redis) but when I tried to retrieve data I got error: **Could not read JSON...** .

Here is part of my code:

Endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getDataById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id)
{
    MyObject data = myService.findOneById(String.valueOf(id));
    return Optional.ofNullable(data)
            .map(mData -> new ResponseEntity<>(mData, HttpStatus.OK))
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

Service:

```
@Cacheable(value = "mydata", key = "#id")
public MyObject findOneById(String id) {
    return myRepository.getOne(Integer.valueOf(id));
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Spring Boot Caching With Redis
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/redis?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    name:
    username: root
    password: root
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
      cachePrepStmts: true
      prepStmtCacheSize: 250
      prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
      useServerPrepStmts: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    show_sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write_dates_as_timestamps: false
  cache:
    type: redis

liquibase:
  change-log: classpath:liquibase/master.xml

server:
  port: 8080

debug: true
```

In my main class I have added **@EnableCaching** annotation and in my **pom.xml** I have added dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

At the end here is the full error that I'm getting from Postman:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-04-16T06:34:27.331+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": 
  "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
  "message": "Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: 
      com.springboot.redis.domains.MyObject$$_jvstdc2_0[\"id\"])",
  "path": "/api/myObject/67"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Cacheable(value = "mydata", key = "#id")
public MyObject findOneById(String id) {
    return myRepository.findOne(Integer.valueOf(id));
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more details on how this your answer helps with this specific question? Thank you.

Comment: That works fine. Here is one useful link about it. getOne only returns the instance of object and it's lazy loaded. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482117/when-use-getone-and-findone-methods-spring-data-jpa