# Intellij debugger step over hibernate objects values are empty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, debugging, intellij-idea

When im stepping over hibnerate objects with Intellij the objects appear to be null in the debugging window.  Labelled as `$$_hibernate_interceptor`

So lets say I have some simple code that looks like the following

```
Subscription subscription  = subscriptionRepository.getOne(1l);
log.info("add breakpoint debug code stopped here")
```

I would like to see what values that have been returned from the subscriptionRepository and assigned to the subscription object within the the `Debug:` window.

See screenshot that shows what this looks like on my computer.

[image]

As you can see most of the Variable values appear to be empty, however if I do a toString() on the subscription object it will output values that are marked as null in the inteceptor window.  So they are not really empty.

So couple of questions here

- What is `$$_hibernate_interceptor`

**Further findings**

The interceptor is only returned when I use the default `repository.getOne`.  If I use findBy or my own findByField it does not call the interceptor and displays the values in the debug window.

What is happening here why does getOne display interceptor but the others dont?

Comment: `getOne()` returns an unitilialized proxy. That's the whole point of that method. Calling a method of that proxy (like toString()) is what will initialize the proxy, i.e. tell Hibernate to execute the query and load the data from the database. So what you see is perfectly normal and expected. That happens through byte-code generation, and the bytebuddy interceptor is (AFAIK) the object that will intercept the method calls and initialize the proxy.

Comment: Thabks for feedback makes sense. So what would be my options to view the object in the debug panel?

Comment: I guess you could use the "evaluate expression" tool to call  `toString()`? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, the type of your Subscription is `Subscription$HibernateProxy$...`. This is because Hibernate is lazy-loading properties from the database as you use them.

Until the first time they are accessed, say, in a `toString()`, they will be null.
You can sidestep this easily by adding a variable watch (the little <kbd>+</kbd> icon) on "subscription.toString()".

The difference between `findById` and `getOne` is that the former returns a lazy proxy, while the latter uses an eagerly loaded object. Some information on why [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47370947/1207791).