# Hibernate - why is a String property lazily loaded?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have a simple entity `Configuration`, which has an ID and a String property.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Wither
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONFIGURATION")
public class Configuration {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CONFIG_OBJECT")
    private String configItem1;
}
```

I have simple JPA repository

```
public interface ConfigurationRepository extends JpaRepository<Configuration, Long> {

}
```

And in a Cucumber test I try to access the field

```
final Configuration configuration = configurationRepository.getOne(1L);//id 1 exists
configuration.getConfigItem1(); //the exception is thrown here
```

But I'm getting this exception
`could not initialize proxy [com.mk.myapp.model.Configuration#1] - no Session`

I assume, that the property `configItem1` is being lazily loaded, but why? I would expect this when I have some entitites in a relation, but why should a String property be lazily loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you used to retreive your Configuration entity `getOne(1)` is always returning a proxy with uninitialzed fields. Only the id field is populated afaik.

Try the `findbyId` method of your repository to get your Configuration and you will find your String field populated.

This question has also been answered before e.g. [When use getOne and findOne methods Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24482117/7634201) so I think this can be closed as a duplicate.